# Update fields in column with full entries from another dataframe where match of first few characters is found

Tags: r

I have a list of UK postcode sector data such as below

| PostcodeSector |
| --- |
| PE4 5 |
| PE28 8 |

I also have a dataset that contains all UK postcodes (entitled FullPostcodes). Reduced example below:

| ColumnID | Postcode |
| --- | --- |
| A | PE4 5BS |
| B | PE28 8LN |
| C | PE4 8DB |
| D | LA2 8LN |

What I am looking to do is update PostcodeSector with the first full value from FullPostcodes 'Postcode' field that is a match to the characters observed in PostcodeSector for each entry - or any random value from FullPostcodes where there is a match to PostcodeSector, whichever is easier. So end result in this example could be:

| PostcodeSector |
| --- |
| PE4 5BS |
| PE28 8LN |

Any help will be very much appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data  <-
tibble::tribble(
  ~PostcodeSector,
          "PE4 5",
         "PE28 8"
  )

postcode <- c("PE4 5BS", "PE28 8LN", "PE4 8DB", "LA2 8LN")

data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(PostcodeSector = postcode[which(str_detect(postcode,PostcodeSector))] )

# A tibble: 2 x 1
# Rowwise: 
  PostcodeSector
  <chr>         
1 PE4 5BS       
2 PE28 8LN
```

Comment: Hi, when I run this I get no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')". Both of my objects are imports from Excel (in your example, 'PostcodeSector' and 'postcode'. Do I need to do some conversion of the objects? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to check your data.frame and variables name and adapt to my code, see that the data.frame here is called data